# How do I remove a class from every other element in a DOM tree once another element is clicked? - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So this is what my DOM tree looks like:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="sidebar">
      <ul>
          <li class="selected"><a href="#">Header 1</a>
              <ul>
                   <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                   <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header 2</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header 3</a>
            <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header 7</a>
             <ul>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header 4</a>
             <ul>
             </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Header 5</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

So when I want to do a simple `addClass` and `removeClass` for one element, this works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div#content div#sidebar ul li a').click(function(e) {
        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) {
            $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        }        
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

However, this doesn't remove the class `selected` from every 'peer' of `$(this).parent()`. It only removes the class from the parent of the currently selected item.

What I want to do is, when you click on the link `Header 2`, it adds the class `selected` to `Header 2`, and checks all the sibling elements (in this case, `li`s for the links `Header 1 - 7`) and removes that class on any siblings if it finds it. So, in effect, there can be only one `selected` at that level in the DOM tree.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function () {
    $('#sidebar > ul > li > a').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#sidebar > ul > li').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

This selects the `<a>` elements nested within the first tier of `<li>` elements and adds the `.selected` class to its parent `<li>` element (while also removing all other instances of the `.selected` class).

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/RRk25/

This could be optimized:

```
$(function () {
    var $first_tier_li = $('#sidebar > ul > li');
    $first_tier_li.children('a').bind('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $first_tier_li.removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
    });
});
```

This saves looking up DOM nodes on every click as they are cached from the time the `document.ready` event fires.

Here's a jsfiddle of the optimization: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/RRk25/1/

Comment: Hey @Jasper, do you mind editing this so the children `ul` elements of the item that will be removed, fadeOut or scrollUp or disappear permanently...while the other one shows itself. Do I have to add some CSS to get that, or can I do that all in jQuery?

Comment: That edit you included about being optimized, makes total sense, because I want to manipulate the `second_tier`, so you have set the groundwork to be able to do that...which is awesome.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/RRk25/2/, here ya go. This uses the `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` functions to show/hide the descendant `<ul>` elements. Note that I added a CSS declaration to hide all second tier `<ul>` tags on load (but I also added inline CSS to the first "sub-nav" `<ul>` so it is shown by default).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the class of all the $('div#content div#sidebar ul li') elements, and then just add the class to the clicked one. Will that work for you?

See it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JAWKk/1/)

Comment: See my new edit. Now I'm not sure what would you like to do when users click on non-headers, but that's about it.